# how to view the logs of android device in nativescript? tns device log is not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, nativescript

I run my app on my physical device, not on an emulator.
after running the app with `tns run` I execute this command to see the logs:

```
$ tns device log --device LGH873DSUed176e08
Searching for devices...
iTunes is not available for this operating system. You will not be able to work with connected iOS devices.
```

And nothing happens after this eventho I've run the app and it's working. what am I doing wrong? I would like to see the sort of logs that are produced when using an emulator. right now I can't even see my own console.log messages.

Comment: The command works as expected on my end and shows the entire device logs. Are you on Mac or Windows? Alternatively you may try directly launching `monitor` from android tools directory Or Android Studio comes with built-in logger you could use.

Comment: you can also run `adb logcat` to see the console.log messages on android

Comment: @Manoj. I'm neither on Mac nor Windows. I'm on Archlinux. I don't use android studio. I've manually installed the SDKs with the android sdkmanager. can you elaborate alittle more on the `monitor`?

Comment: @WilliamJuan adb logcat looks good I guess I have to use the pid, how do I find the pid of the process on my android? I have no idea how many processes tns is running for me on android and which ones I need. and how to find their pid.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay I usually filter on 'JS', so the command looks like this `adb logcat | grep 'JS'`